# dynamically added table is not displayed in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

there is something going wrong , such that firstly i created separately xml file for table row ,it did not work, then i created table row and text view programatically, again it is not displayed when i run , i can not get if what is wrong with my code

```
    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.goodsTable);     
    for (int i = 0; i < attrName.length; i++) {

                            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            TextView atName = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                            atName.setText(attrName[i]);
                            tr.addView(atName);
                            table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                        }
                        table.requestLayout();
```

Comment: and this is code which i mentioned above,using xml file                                                                             TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.attribute_row, table, false);
                        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.attributeName)).setText(attrName[i]);
                        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.attributeValue)).setText(barcode);
                        table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

```
for (int i = 0; i < attrName.length; i++) {

         TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
         tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

         TextView atName = new TextView(this);
         atName.setText(attrName[i]);
         atName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(atName);
         table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

You must apply `LayoutParam` for `TextView` and for create new Object for `TableRow` or `TextView` you should use `Activity Context` not `ApplicationContext`

Comment: when i use 'this' instead of 'getApplicationContext()', it gives error, i want to note that my code is inside of  searchButton.setOnClickListener

Comment: Use `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: thank you so muuch @ahishek ,yo made my day ,thank you